# standardise data using list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to standardise observations for a group of columns in a dataframe I have without using any in built functions.

I have a list of indexes of the columns I want to standardise held in an object called continuous and I'm trying to use list comprehension to apply the standardisation.

I'm having trouble coming up with an approach that allows me to iterate over the rows in my dataframe.

What I've got so far:

```
continuous = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

data_z = [(data[col][i] for i in data.index)-data.mean(col)/data.std(col) for col in continuous]
```

This is spitting out a type error - it won't let me iterate over a generator object, so I'm wondering if anyone knows the correct approach to iterate over the rows and columns I want to standardise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend not to use a list comprehension in order to have a clearer code. This will make it easier also for you to structure the code in a cleaner way. I like list comprehensions very much, but I avoid to use them when they start to grow that much!

Comment: What is the error, in your code `col` is an integer not a series/column, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

Comment: I think the operation you're trying to perform is best done with a vectorized approach, I assume you want to subtract the mean of each column and scale by its std, that's actually a pretty panda-esque operation if there ever was one. See if my solution gives you the expected results

Comment: Yes nearly - subtract the mean from each observation and divide by the standard deviation for the columns I want. I'm happy with any approach to be honest, I'm just not allowed to use any inbuilt function from things like scipy.stats or sklearn etc. I saw your answer below - I think it's close but I get a keyError. I think because continuous is a list of integers rather than column indexes for my df?

Comment: It depends on what your column names are. You can use df.columns to get a list of the existing columns. If you must use native python, I suggested using a nested loop over list comprehension, they are usually meant for shorter constructions

Comment: So for example, where the first element of continuous is 1, 1 should represent the second column of my dataframe labelled data, and the name of that column is "Rented Bike Count". I'm just trying to use continuous as a way of extracting the columns from data that are continuous.

Comment: The issue with my answer was that I double nested the list of columns ,that was my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with filtered columns in `df1`:

```
np.random.seed(2021)    
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(13, 13)))

continuous = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

df1 = data[continuous]
data_z = df1.sub(df1.mean()).div(df1.std())
```

---

```
print (data_z)
          1         2         3         5         6         7         8   \
0   0.361158  1.309808 -1.365801  0.092504  0.739880  0.553102  0.549700   
1  -1.083473 -1.038813  0.309238 -1.410680 -0.977698 -0.944883 -1.314501   
2  -1.083473  0.429075  0.979254  0.393140  1.083396  0.253505  0.549700   
3  -0.722315  1.016230  0.309238 -1.110043 -1.664730  1.451893 -0.693101   
4   1.805788 -0.158080  1.649269  1.295050  0.396364  0.852699 -0.071700   
5  -0.722315 -1.332391 -0.025770 -0.508770 -1.664730  1.451893 -0.071700   
6  -1.083473  0.135497  0.979254  1.295050 -0.290667 -1.244480 -1.314501   
7   1.083473 -1.332391 -0.360778  0.393140  1.083396 -0.345689  1.481801   
8   1.444630  1.309808 -1.365801 -1.410680  0.396364 -1.244480 -1.003801   
9   0.000000 -1.038813  0.979254 -0.208133  1.083396  0.553102  0.549700   
10 -0.361158 -0.745236 -1.365801  0.693777 -0.634183  0.553102 -1.003801   
11 -0.361158  0.722653 -0.695785  1.295050 -0.290667 -0.645286  0.860401   
12  0.722315  0.722653 -0.025770 -0.809406  0.739880 -1.244480  1.481801   

          9         10  
0   0.369274  0.301124  
1  -1.107823  0.301124  
2   1.477098 -1.264720  
3   0.738549 -0.090337  
4  -0.738549 -1.264720  
5  -1.107823 -0.873259  
6  -0.369274  1.475507  
7  -1.477098 -0.873259  
8  -0.738549  0.301124  
9   0.738549 -0.481798  
10  0.738549 -0.481798  
11  1.477098  1.475507  
12  0.000000  1.475507
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just as easily do

```
mean = data[continuous].mean(axis='rows')
std = data[continuous].std(axis='rows')

data_z = (data[continuous] - mean ) / std
```